# Google Test pre-build VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, googletest

I have a solution which was compiled with compiler VS2008. It was working perfect. It is instrumented with Google Test and the Google Test library is linked to the solution. the `gtest.lib` should be compiled with the same compiler as the solution itself, as far as I know.

Now, I have to compile this same solution with VS2013. I get this compilation error

```
Error   3   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': 
value '1700' doesn't match value '1800'
```

I think that I should get the library for Google Test compiled with Visual Studio 2013.

I cannot find such thing. **Could you give me a hint at the Google Test library I should go for ?**

Comment: GoogleTest is very easy to compile yourself. Just grab the source, and either use CMake to generate a VS solution, or use the custom solutions in the msvc subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a prebuilt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker error you get is pretty obvious: You need a `gtest.lib` compiled with VS2013.

> *"I think that I should get the library for Google Test compiled with Visual Studio 2013."*

Exactly, so *just do* that.

> *"**Could you give me a hint at the Google Test library I should go for ?**"*

Well, no more as to cite from the [google test primer documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Setting_up_a_New_Test_Project) (emphasis mine), sorry (I doubt you can reliably download a proper binary elsewhere):

> #### Setting up a New Test Project
>
> To write a test program using Google Test, you need to compile Google Test into a library and link your test with it. We provide build files for some popular build systems: msvc/ **for Visual Studio**, xcode/ for Mac Xcode, make/ for GNU make, codegear/ for Borland C++ Builder, and the autotools script (deprecated) **and CMakeLists.txt for CMake** (recommended) in the Google Test root directory. If your build system is not on this list, you can take a look at make/Makefile to learn how Google Test should be compiled (basically you want to compile src/gtest-all.cc with GTEST_ROOT and GTEST_ROOT/include in the header search path, where GTEST_ROOT is the Google Test root directory).
>
> Once you are able to compile the Google Test library, you should create a project or build target for your test program. Make sure you have GTEST_ROOT/include in the header search path so that the compiler can find "gtest/gtest.h" when compiling your test. Set up your test project to link with the Google Test library (for example, in Visual Studio, this is done by adding a dependency on gtest.vcproj).
>
> If you still have questions, take a look at how Google Test's own tests are built and use them as examples.

I personally prefer to build the test runner using the `src/gtest-all.cc` to be built and linked with my test-projects from source. That's the most simple and mostly portable way IMHO (using e.g. your custom GNU makefiles).

As said in the comment on your OP, you can easily do a *"prebuild"* just using your VS2013 compiler, to link with it from other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there's a [native GTEST package on NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/gtest) which contains a `gtest.lib`. Has the additional benefit of making the gtest `include` folder automatically available.